# How to convert a list into multiple sublists of a list?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, text-processing

I have a list of items, i want to make sublists in the same list.

my list looks some thing like this..

```
lst=['(a) subp1;\n', '(A) subp1;\n', '(1) subp1;\n', '(2) subp1;\n', '(b) subp1;\n', '(i) subpb; and\n', '(ii) subpb; and\n', '(iii) subpb; and\n', '(c) subp3.\n']

if (ij) comes in pair never comes alone like(i) or (j) always (ij) and it is lower

(i) is roman
```

```
lst1=[]
for item in lst:
      lst1.append(item)
```

I want some thing like

```
if item[1].islower() till next item[1].islower i need as one sublist
```

my expected output

```
[['(a) subp1;\n', '(A) subp1;\n', '(1) subp1;\n', '(2) subp1;\n'], 
  ['(b) subp1;\n', '(i) subpb; and\n', '(ii) subpb; and\n', '(iii) subpb; and\n'], 
  ['(c) subp3.\n']]
```

Comment: `i` also satisfies the condition to generate a new sublist. Could you be more specific on the splitting criteria?

Comment: no,that comes under roman number. in my case i and j appear in pair like this (ij) to differentiate between roman and lowercase. only (i) treated as roman number 1

Comment: @SS you should specify that in the question - you're saying something completely different

Comment: yeah edited @Gsk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have also roman numerals to count, I'd avoid `.islower()`.

A solution is to create a list of the valid separators, and when you encounter them append a sublist to your list and append items to the last sublist:

```
import string

lst=['(a) subp1;\n', '(A) subp1;\n', '(1) subp1;\n', '(2) subp1;\n', '(b) subp1;\n', '(i) subpb; and\n', '(ii) subpb; and\n', '(iii) subpb; and\n', '(c) subp3.\n']

# all ascii lowercase letter, replacing 'i' with 'ij'
separators = [letter if letter != "i" else "ij" for letter in string.ascii_lowercase]

lst1=[]
for item in lst:
    if item[1] in separators:
        lst1.append([])
    lst1[-1].append(item)

print(lst1)
```

**Output:**

> `[['(a) subp1;\n', '(A) subp1;\n', '(1) subp1;\n', '(2) subp1;\n'], ['(b) subp1;\n', '(i) subpb; and\n', '(ii) subpb; and\n', '(iii) subpb; and\n'], ['(c) subp3.\n']]`

If you're working with all Roman numerals, you want to consider all of them:
`i, v, x, l, c, d, m`

Just replace in `separators` the letters representing the Roman numerals with the related placeholder

Comment: it will not go more than xv

Comment: @SS Just replace the single letters. Is it working?